# Blu-Ray reader won't read Blu-Ray discs. no issues reading DVDs

Tags: dvd, blu-ray

as title.

I've tried several Blu-Ray titles and none of them worked. I tried the same discs on the PS3 and no issues playing them.

I also tried DVD discs on the Blu-Ray drive and I had no problems with them.

I downloaded a trial copy of DVDFab and also VLC on the desktop to test the Blu-Ray and DVD discs.

Is it possible that the Blu-Ray components on the drive is not working while the DVD/CD bits are ok? Like perhaps it uses 2 lasers?

Thanks

Comment: Since when you have these issues?? I have problem with all blu ray too and seems strange that BluRay head fails without using it. Do you have updated Windows 10?? I suspect something gone wrong with some driver.

Comment: I know you asked this 3 years ago, but for anyone else searching this: I've found that a number of eBay sellers are selling portable DVD USB drives, but labelling them as "Blu Ray" (many have very little technical knowledge about the difference). I bought one and it could not read any Blu Ray discs, and only showed up in Windows as a DVD drive. I bought a more reputable brand (Lite-On) and it shows up as "BR-ROM" and reads BR discs correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are using different laser heads.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that an optical drive actually have 3 laser heads. One for CD. One for DVD. And one for Blu-ray. So yes, if one breaks (typically from overheating), you will still be able to play the other two types of discs.

What typically happens is that the lens becomes skewed due to heat - because the manufacturers makes them of plastic rather than glass. And then it can't read the disc anymore. (Some manufacturers do use glass lenses though).

One can wonder if manufacturers use plastic lenses as a "timer" to get consumers to buy new stuff. However, I've had a few Blu-ray Players run for 12+ hours daily for 4 months now, displaying video in a few stores in town. Partly to test their durability. And I must say I've been surprised. I expected to see this lens issue after a month or so, but no. Still running.